# How can I avoid getting a message saying an object is not defined?

Tags: javascript

I have code that does this:

```
$scope.grid.data = null;
```

However it could be the case that $scope.grid has not yet been defined. If that's the case then how could I avoid trying to do this assignment?

Answer (score 4):

```
if($scope.grid){
  $scope.grid.data = null;
}
```

Can find more elaborate response here: [JavaScript object detection: dot syntax versus 'in' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174748/javascript-object-detection-dot-syntax-versus-in-keyword)

Comment: this is side effecting. If $scope.grid has an actual getter the check can alter the state.