# Javascript filter function polyfill

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am unable to understand why check corresponding to line  `if (i in t)` - Line no.18 is placed in [filter function polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) :

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun/*, thisArg*/) {
    'use strict';

    if (this === void 0 || this === null) {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var res = [];
    var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t) {
        var val = t[i];

        // NOTE: Technically this should Object.defineProperty at
        //       the next index, as push can be affected by
        //       properties on Object.prototype and Array.prototype.
        //       But that method's new, and collisions should be
        //       rare, so use the more-compatible alternative.
        if (fun.call(thisArg, val, i, t)) {
          res.push(val);
        }
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Comment: Do we need to check if (i in t) when we are using a for loop to loop over array elements?

Answer (score 6):

It is to avoid the elements which are not defined yet, in the sparse arrays. See the following example,

```
var array = [];
array[3] = 10;
console.log(array.length);
// 4
```

So, the length of the array is 4, but only the element at index `3` is defined, all others are not defined yet. So, if you do

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(i, array[i]);
}
```

you will get

```
0 undefined
1 undefined
2 undefined
3 10
```

Arrays are special JavaScript objects. The indices are just properties in the array object.  Whenever you extend the array object with an index which is not in the array, the `length` property will be adjusted internally. In this case, there is only one property in the array object, with the name `3` defined. But we are trying to access elements from 0 to 3. So it returns `undefined` for all the indices which are not present in the array object yet.

To avoid that, we are checking if the current index is really defined in the array object, with that `if` statement.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (i in array) {
        console.log(i, array[i]);
    }
}
```

would print

```
3 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because it's possible for JavaScript arrays to have gaps.

For example, consider the following:

```
var a = ["hello", "howdy", "welcome"];

delete greetings[1];

"0" in a; // true
"1" in a; // false
"2" in a; // true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.myFilter = function(callBack) {
 let newArray = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
  let result = callBack(this[i], i, this);
    if (result) {
     newArray.push(this[i]);
    }
}
return newArray;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution. Please add some explanation with your code, to help others understand why it works, when the question didn't!

Answer (score 0):

IN is a reserved keyword which can be used in for and if statement.

`18th line they are doing exist check`

Refer this [dot vs in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174748/javascript-object-detection-dot-syntax-versus-in-keyword).

Answer (score 0):

Create own **`filter()`** method

```js
Array.prototype.newFilter = function(func){
  let filtered = [], n = this.length;
  
  for(let i = 0; i<n; i++) {
   if(func(this[i],i,this)) 
    filtered.push(this[i]);
  }
  return filtered;
}

let result = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].newFilter(item => item > 4);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.myFilter = function(callBackFn) {
    let res = [];
    if (!Array.isArray(this)) {
        throw new Error(`${this} is not a function`);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i<this.length; i++) {
        if (callBackFn(this[i], i, this)) {
            res.push(this[i])
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).