# JavaScript: hasOwnProperty vs dot syntax

Tags: javascript, hasownproperty

Imagine there is an object: `foo = {"bar": 1}`

Is there any benefit to use `hasOwnProperty` over dot-syntax to check for `bar` property inside `foo` object:

```
if (foo.hasOwnProperty('bar') {
  // do something
}
```

vs

```
if (foo.bar) {
  // do something
}
```

Also:

- what will hapen if `foo["bar"]` is `undefined`?
- what if `foo` `undefined`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at this example,

```js
Object.prototype.baz = 100;
var foo = {"bar": 1}

// will be false because in foo object there is no baz property 
// hasOwnProperty checks that the object has the specified property 
// and does not check that property in the prototype chain
if (foo.hasOwnProperty('baz')) {
  console.log('foo.hasOwnProperty("baz")');
}


//  will be true because baz property will be found 
//  in parent object through prototype chain
if (foo.baz) {
  console.log('foo.baz');
}
```

Comment: strongly disagree. Better explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174748/javascript-object-detection-dot-syntax-versus-in-keyword